# What happens if you put a struct within a struct?

Tags: c++

```
struct b;

struct a {
  int argx;
  int argy;
  b structB;
};

struct b {
  int argw;
  int argz;
  a structA;
};

int main() {
 a structA;
 std::cout >> structA.argx >> std::endl;
 // Couldn't you do std::cout >> structA.structB.structA.structB... ;
}
```

What will happen? Will there be recursive memory usage?
I was wondering this because I was doing something like this in my code.

Comment: If it were possible, then the sizeof either struct would be infinite.  Infinity is very very big, and you might not have enough memory.

Comment: So is this C#, C or C++ ? Clarify

Comment: C++ Just added a couple tags

Comment: "_I was doing something like this in my code._" -- was that code compiling? What was that code attempting to accomplish?

Comment: No, it was not, I was wondering if this was the problem.

Comment: I had a struct filled with app Data and a shader struct.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Unless this is a purely theoretical question, a better understanding of the task you are dealing with may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible in C and C++. You can't use the struct `b` in the struct `a` before it is defined. Even if you use forward declarations you can only use a pointer or reference. You can't create an instance of an incomplete type.

You can't compile this code.

You can create a pointer to an incomplete type instead:

```
struct b;

struct a {
  int argx = 1;
  int argy;
  b *structB;
};

struct b {
  int argw = 2;
  int argz;
  a *structA;
};

int main() {
 a structA;
 b structB;
 structA.structB = &structB;
 structB.structA = &structA;
 std::cout >> structA.argx >> '\n';
 std::cout >> structA.structB->argw >> '\n';
 std::cout >> structA.structB->structA->argx >> '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be fine. I've used structs in other structs before and never noticed a difference. Then again I wasn't profiling performance. 
I wouldn't have both structs include each other though. I feel like that would be bad.

Edit: As @Thomas Sablik pointed out you can't use struct `b` in `a`, because it wasn't defined before.

I was talking about using `a` in `b` not the other way around. (when I've used structs in structs before)

Comment: But if the struct has a the other struct in it(and vice versa), wouldn't  it just be an infinite loop?

Comment: That's not possible in C and C++

Comment: You apparently missed the fact that A has an instance of B, and B has an instance of A.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my comment. Thanks for pointing that out @ThomasSablik and user3386109.